# SQL - Take a Column, Split it into New Columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

Example table:

```
  ID    CB        CB2   CB3   CB4    CB5
  ----  --------  ----  ----  ----  ----
  1     亀 龜 龜
  2     竜 龒
```

Note: Each character is separated by a space.
Note: The number of characters in CB varies.

I would like to move each character in column CB (after the first) to its own, separate, column, so that no more than one character is in each column.

Like this:

```
  ID    CB    CB2   CB3   CB4    CB5
  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----
  1      亀    龜    龜
  2      竜    龒
```

Note: New column names don't need to have the format shown in the example.

(SQLite)

Comment: You need to have a maximum number of characters.  A SQL query cannot have a variable number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, you can do this with a recursive CTE.  The following gets the characters:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select id, substr(cb, 1, instr(cb, ' ') - 1) as chr,
             substr(cb, instr(cb, ' ') + 1) as rest, 1 as lev
      from t
      union all
      select id, substr(rest, 1, instr(rest || ' ', ' ') - 1) as chr,
             substr(rest, instr(rest || ' ', ' ') + 1) as rest, lev + 1 as lev
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select *
from cte;
```

You can pivot these . . . for a fixed number of columns:

```
select id,
       max(case when lev = 1 then chr end) as chr_1,
       max(case when lev = 2 then chr end) as chr_2,
       max(case when lev = 3 then chr end) as chr_3
from cte
group by id;
```

Here is a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fMo8obdKZUm2oU4m3VWN8v/2).

Comment: @Afh . . . No, this is a `select` query.  Your table as described only has two columns, so it could not be put into that table.  You could insert the rows into another table.

Comment: I’m sorry for not being clear in my question. I was hoping to modify the table. If it isn’t possible to create the columns and add data to them in one execution, then I will add columns CB2, CB3, CB4, and CB5 to the table. What would the next step be?